# After authorise the Google editor add-ons, How can we navigate to a new page on successful authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

In our Google Editor add-ons,we have implemented a logout where we reset the service. [OuthClient2 for appscript](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2)

```
function logout() {
 var service = getDriveService();
  service.reset();
}
```

After logging out, in the same instance (without refreshing the page) if we try to login (authorize) the add-on it throws an error.

> "Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context. (line 3, file "Code")"  Is there a workaround with this?

Comment: I would guess that you tried opening the document from a script and in that case the user interface is not available.  The ui is only available when a user opens the document.

Comment: @Cooper, No. While the document is open, I logged out and with the same instance when I try to login, it seems to throw the above error. Have observed this error with the add-on available in the market place as well called "Lucid charts". You could give it a try

Comment: We'll need more context on what service is, what logout does and where do you get the UI

Comment: I'd recommend that you don't log out.

Comment: @Martí, We are using the outh2client Service. Have added the link above.

Comment: @Cooper, I wish that was an option.

Comment: Is `DocumentApp.getUi()` inside a function? Also, what are you using the UI for?

Comment: @Martí, So the user flow is after we logout, we show the login page and after successful login, we show the user the home screen. Now what happens in the above scenario is that in the same instance we cannot logout and login with the above home screen. When we reload the document, the login works. We get the above error.

Comment: This is not what I was asking. I already understood that ;) I was asking if the line `DocumentApp.getUi()` is inside a function and when are you using its result it.

Comment: @Martí, I quite did not understand.  It is inside a function being called in the callback function after authorize. Does that help?

Comment: Okey, a few more questions: Are accessing a Google service or it's from another server?  Also it seems that the callback is actually a page. Are you trying to get the UI from there?

Comment: @Martí  We are using OuthClient2 to gain access to our servers. Using the Service, we have a callback function it is returning to, Here we are making a call to the function which loads a new html.

Comment: Hey @Martí, Any luck?
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure how OAuthClient2 works... It seems like in the callback you have to return the HTML directly and not use `getUi` but I don't know.

Comment: @Martí, Thanks for trying. :)